# Body was inferred to be an attribute in one code snippet, but the other runs fine. Can't find the difference between the two

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, webserver

The bottom, currently commented out section was what I got from [a guide in Microsoft's documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) It runs perfectly fine and using Postman I can submit get, post, put, and delete requests as expected.

I tried to make my own using the documentation as a guide, but I get an error. I don't know what the difference is between the two, so any help would be massively appreciated.

Error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Body was inferred but the method does not allow inferred body parameters.
Below is the list of parameters that we found:

Parameter | Source
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
db1 | Body (Inferred)


Did you mean to register the "Body (Inferred)" parameter(s) as a Service or apply the [FromServices] or [FromBody] attribute?
```

Code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TodoDb>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("UserList"));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
var app = builder.Build();



app.MapGet("/users/all", async (UserDB db1) =>
    await db1.Users.ToListAsync());

app.MapGet("/users/current", async (UserDB db2) =>
    await db2.Users.Where(u => u.lastOffense.ToString("yyyy MMMM") == DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MMMM")).ToListAsync());

app.MapGet("/login/{username}", async (string username, UserDB db3) =>
{
    var user = await db3.Users.FindAsync(username);
    if (user is null)
    {
        user = new User();
        user.username = username;
        user.lastOffense = DateTime.Now;
        user.offenses = 1;
        await db3.Users.AddAsync(user);
    } else
    {
        user.offenses += 1;
    }

    await db3.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Results.NoContent();

});

app.Run();


 /*

app.MapGet("/todoitems", async (TodoDb db) => 
    await db.Todos.ToListAsync());


app.MapGet("/todoitems/complete", async (TodoDb db) =>
    await db.Todos.Where(t => t.IsComplete).ToListAsync());

app.MapGet("/todoitems/incomplete", async (TodoDb db) =>
    await db.Todos.Where(t => t.IsComplete).ToListAsync());

app.MapGet("/todoitems/{id}", async (int id, TodoDb db) =>
    await db.Todos.FindAsync(id)
        is Todo todo
            ? Results.Ok(todo)
            : Results.NotFound());

app.MapPost("/todoitems", async (Todo todo, TodoDb db) =>
{
    db.Todos.Add(todo);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Results.Created($"/todoitems/{todo.Id}", todo);
});

app.MapPut("/todoitems/{id}", async (int id, Todo inputTodo, TodoDb db) =>
{
    var todo = await db.Todos.FindAsync(id);

    if (todo is null) return Results.NotFound();

    todo.name = inputTodo.name;
    todo.IsComplete = inputTodo.IsComplete;

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Results.NoContent();

});

app.MapDelete("/todoitems/{id}", async (int id, TodoDb db) =>
{
    if (await db.Todos.FindAsync(id) is Todo todo)
    {
        db.Todos.Remove(todo);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Results.Ok(todo);
    }

    return Results.NotFound();
});

app.Run();

*/
```

I've tried changing from MapGet() to MapPost(), and it does work, but from my understanding, that's not what I'm supposed to do in this scenario when I'm just trying to retrieve information. Even if MapPost() was fine to use, I still don't quite understand what the difference between mine and the documentation is to be throwing an error.

Comment: `AddDbContext<TodoDb>` presumably you wanted to add UserDB instead of TodoDB here.

Comment: @Ralf Fixed my issue. Can't believe I missed such an obvious thing. Appreciate it, thanks a ton!